# check different sequence primary to standby oracle RAC

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

I'm trying to make the difference of sequences between the primary and the wait in the RAC oracle.
but I can not get the query to wait, this is an example in stanbdy:

```
 set serveroutput on
 SET FEEDBACK OFF
 DECLARE NS VARCHAR2(50);
 C NUMBER(10) := 0;
 LS NUMBER(10);
 TIMED VARCHAR2(50);
 BEGIN FOR n IN( SELECT MAX(FIRST_TIME) Time FROM V$LOG_HISTORY GROUP BY THREAD#)
    LOOP
    NS := n.Time;
    select to_char(max(FIRST_TIME),'DD-MON-YY:HH24:MI:SS') Time, max(sequence#) sequence# INTO TIMED, LS from v$log_history where FIRST_TIME >=( NS);
        dbms_output.put_line( TIMED || ' ' || LS || ' ' || C);
    END LOOP
    END
 /
```

**apply on standby, this return always :**

```
26-NOV-18:14:40:36  61210
26-NOV-18:14:42:38  61210
26-NOV-18:14:47:19  61210
```

**for 3 RAC
need return apply on standby:**

```
26-NOV-18:14:40:36  720
26-NOV-18:14:42:38  61210
26-NOV-18:14:47:19  3459
```

sequence is different! thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

*You need to prefix dynamic performance views with a `g` for RAC systems.*

i.e. replace `v$log_history` with `gv$log_history`.